# Start process at startup

Tags: startup, webmin

I have installed JDownloader on my Debian based NAS System and want to get JDownloader starting at boot.

I have setup a script in /etc/init.d/jdownloader and can start JD with SSH like `/etc/init.d/jdownloader start` or `service jdownloader start` and a user jdownload:jdownload. But how to run JD at startup of my NAS System for this user?

I also found the point "Bootconfiguration (SysV)" in my Webmin installation. but don't know how to use it in my case.

[image: Webmin]

Which ID? Which execution level? And which process I have to entering to run JD as jdownload:jdownload?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is your Debian using SystemV init or the newer systemd init?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. How to find out?

Comment: `cat /etc/*-release`

Comment: PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian

Comment: That means you're using systemd as a init system.